How do I resolve "Cannot find module" error using Node.js? node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998 throw err;
At Beginning, I try npm i to install packages, error:
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path my_project_folder\node_modules
npm ERR! errno -4052
npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, mkdir 'my_project_folder\node_modules'

I don't know why it cannot automatically generate the node_modules folder?
To fix this bug, I manually made the node_modules folder, and try 'npm i', it seems successfully:
added 2 packages, and audited 3 packages in 9s

found 0 vulnerabilities

but when I run node server.js, another bug:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'dayjs'

But when I rum npm list, it shows:
05@1.0.0 my_project_folder
├── dayjs@1.11.7
└── lodash@4.17.21

package.json is under the my_project_folder (the root folder)
server.js is under the my_project_folder (the root folder)
in package.json, I use "type": "CommonJS", and in server.js, I use const dayjs = require('dayjs')
I really want to understand what is going on here, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to where to look next. Any suggestions?

That first error is worrying. Can you actually see the libraries installed in the node_modules directory?
